# exporting Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I'm using the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage in VS2012. I'm wondering if there's any export posibility to create a .chm/word/pdf/etc

Thanks. Guillermo.